# How can you determine whether a journal is indexed in ISI or SCI?

Tags: journals, indexing

What are the main difference between SCI and ISI Journals? 
How  can you determine whether a a journal is indexed in SCI or ISI?

Comment: Did you google what do these acronyms mean? It would serve the purpose.

Comment: _What are the main difference between SCI and ISI Journals?_ — The only difference is that one type of journal is indexed in SCI, and the other type is indexed in ISI, and even that is only significant if your local academic bureaucracy cares.  (Mine doesn't.)

Answer (score 6):

[International Scientific Indexing (ISI)](https://isindexing.com/isi/journals.php) has a list on their website. The same is valid for the [Science Citation Index (SCI)](http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/cgi-bin/jrnlst/jloptions.cgi?PC=K). You can search for journals by title.

Comment: The latter link (WoS) now gives only a list of SCIE journals (SCI extended). Is it possible to get a list of SCI journals (preferably downloadable in a standard format)?

Comment: The former (ISI) does not show many well-known journals in all journals list (while still showing less known journals and marking them 'not indexed').